# I got a KeyError when i try to use request.META['CSRF_COOKIE']

Tags: python, django, mako

I want to use the mako template in django2, but when I set up the render function of mako and tried to set the template to bring the csrf token, I found that I could not get the CSRF__COOKIE in request.META

```
#coding:utf-8

from mako.lookup import TemplateLookup
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.conf import settings
from django.template.context import Context
from django.http import HttpResponse


def render_to_response(request, template, data=None):
    context_instance = RequestContext(request)
    path = settings.TEMPLATES[0]['DIRS'][0]
    lookup = TemplateLookup(
        directories=[path],
        output_encoding='utf-8',
        input_encoding='utf-8'
    )
    mako_template = lookup.get_template(template)

    if not data:
        data = {}

    if context_instance:
        context_instance.update(data)
    else:
        context_instance = Context(data)

    result = {}

    for d in context_instance:
        result.update(d)

    result['csrf_token'] = '<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{0}" />'.format(request.META['CSRF_COOKIE'])
    return HttpResponse(mako_template.render(**result))
```

django reports error: KeyError "CSRF_COOKIE", what shoud i do?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, and I used this code https://django.readthedocs.io/en/2.2.x/_modules/django/middleware/csrf.html to fix it.

Write one if statement to judge if the `request.META['CSRF_COOKIE']` exists.

Do not forget to import all the useful things:

```
    if 'CSRF_COOKIE' not in request.META:
        csrf_secret = _get_new_csrf_string()
        request.META['CSRF_COOKIE'] = _salt_cipher_secret(csrf_secret)
        result['csrf_token'] = ('<input type="hidden" id="django-csrf-token"'
                                ' name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value={0}'
                                ' />'.format(request.META['CSRF_COOKIE']))

    else:
        csrf_secret = _unsalt_cipher_token(request.META["CSRF_COOKIE"])
        result['csrf_token'] = ('<input type="hidden" id="django-csrf-token"'
                                ' name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value={0}'
                                ' />'.format(request.META['CSRF_COOKIE']))
```